# Proper app architecture for integrating with built-in apps

Tags: architecture, blackberry, integration

I would like to receive mail message data via a menu item from the messenger application.

I understand how this works with the RIM API.  After registering a menu item with the RIM app, when a user clicks on the menu item, a new process of MyApp gets started and passed the appropriate object.

I'd like to know the best way to pass the incoming object from the process invoked by the RIM app (Messenger for example) to my already running app process.

Is a shared persistent data store dedicated to the transfer the answer?  Or, some type of RPC between multiple processes of my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the kind of thing that the RuntimeStore can do for you. Your one of your process singleton objects can be stored in the RuntimeStore, your menu item can then retrieve it and call the appropriate method to have the message object reference transfered to your process, and operate the semaphores to wake up your process thread to operate on the message object.